# Asterisk not playing audio

Tags: asterisk, voip

I installed Asterisk 13 on Debian 9, and I tried in several different ways to play an audio file and I call, asterisk answers but it doesn't play the file. Here is my extensions.conf:

```
[ivr1]
exten => s,1,NoOp(IVR1)
same => n,Answer
same => n,Read(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom/welcome)
same => n,WaitExten(5)

exten => 6598,1,Goto(ivr1,s,1)
```

Asterisk shows:

```
-- Executing [6598@ivr1:1] Goto("SIP/user-cc-0000001c", "ivr1,s,1") in new stack
-- Goto (ivr1,s,1)
-- Executing [s@ivr1:1] NoOp("SIP/user-cc-0000001c", "IVR1") in new stack
-- Executing [s@ivr1:2] Answer("SIP/user-cc-0000001c", "") in new stack
-- Executing [s@ivr1:3] Read("SIP/user-cc-0000001c", "/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/custom/welcome") in new stack
-- User disconnected
```

I tried with 2 different SIP Clients and the sounds doesn't play. I tried with different codecs and still doesn't play.

Any ideas what could it be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try to understand first what's going on with signaling and media exchange. Capture the activity on the network interface(s) during the calls. Tools like tcpdump or ngrep would do. See if the media is being produced by Asterisk (there must be RTP packets going out from Asterisk to the clients). Check that Asterisk is receiving media from the clients too, what IP addresses the media comes from and whether Asterisk is sending audio to the right IP address or perhaps to an unreachable natted IP address that the client is publishing in its SDP.

Answer (score 0):

You should open rtp ports(default 10000-20000) in your firewall.

Also need ensure you have correct nat settings for your network type.

Comment: If the connection cannot be established wouldn't I get an error message in log? Also, the nat I am not routing, the connection is direct to the Internet, do I have to change something?

Comment: Sure no. If firewalled asterisk never know about that.

Comment: I opened the rtp ports but still sound doesn't play. I executed iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT
Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Disable SIPALG on router. Check your nat settings on asterisk and ensure it configured acordinly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using read function in a wrong way, it has to be something like this.

```
read(variable_name,sound_file)
```

please check link for further information

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/The+Read+Application

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested but still asterisk doesn't play anything. I can connect to the extension but it doesn't play any sound. I suspect that it could be some issue with iptables. I tried dropping iptables rules and accept all connections but still it doesn't play. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Usage is definitely like the one I mention before,  my suggestion might be , chek sound file path ( default should be like /var/lib/asterisks/sounds/en/your file folder ), chek file is compatible with asterisk can play  or use asterisk -r on cli to see what happend when it's come to read step. I hope it's works

Answer (score 0):

You should run a pcap at your client and on the asterisk server.  Use wireshark to perform the capture.  You should see signalling for the call setup and then the associate RTP.  If you see RTP sent by asterisk and not received at your client then you have a firewall issue.  You should be able to see the SDP in the SIP signalling to determine what ports are being requested by the client and asterisk.  Compare that with your firewall settings.  Generally speaking if your client is behind a NAT then you will need to make sure that comedia is enabled in asterisk (nat settings).  You will also want to make sure to disable SIP ALG on your client-side firewall too.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a NAT issue, so open your sip.conf and add the following on your peers

```
nat=yes ;for older asterisks versions
```

or

```
nat=force_rport,comedia ;for newer versions of asterisk
```

then on your CLI run sip reload